# Timing of meditation

Tags: time, meditation-practicalities

I meditate once a day in early morning, only. I have found that this time is very helpful in practicing meditation. I want to meditate at least twice a day. I want to know if time plays a role in practicing meditation ? If yes, then how? At what time does meditation practice become the most intense ?

Comment: This seems very broad. Could you elaborate on a specific question?

Comment: Are you asking when is the optimal time to meditate?

Comment: I tried making my question specific. @Matthew yes it is about asking the optimal time to meditate. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My morning meditation is my clearest meditation.

I also take quiet breaks a couple times a day. Sometimes I even fall asleep for 10-20 minutes. It renews me.

The evening meditation is important to me to clear away the unresolved issues in the day and prepares me for the rest that is so important for a stable mind in these uncertain and stressful times.
http://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/231282-zen-mind-beginner-s-mind

> “So we should be concentrated with our full mind and body on what we
>   do; and we should be faithful, subjectively and objectively, to
>   ourselves, and especially to our feelings. Even when you do not feel
>   so well, it is better to express how you feel without any particular
>   attachment or intention. So you may say, “Oh, I am sorry, I do not
>   feel well.”  ― Shunryu Suzuki, Zen Mind, Beginner's Mind: Informal
>   Talks on Zen Meditation and Practice

http://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/62707.Shunryu_Suzuki

> “When you accept everything, everything is beyond dimensions. The
>   earth is not great nor a grain of sand small. In the realm of Great
>   Activity picking up a grain of sand is the same as taking up the whole
>   universe. To save one sentient being is to save all sentient beings.
>   Your efforts of this moment to save one person is the same as the
>   eternal merit of Buddha.”  ― Shunryu Suzuki

Some suggest that as long as we are aware we meditate. We do dishes aware, we walk aware, we shower aware. Certainly we have meditation practice but to expand that beyond a ritual and a routine is the opening to an extraordinary life.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking the practice to 2 sessions is helpful and advisable. In case you experience any hindrances at a particular session you have at least the other session which might be more productive.